# How to implement prop types on a Typescript function with a Material-UI button?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, material-ui, react-props

First of all, my excuses if I'm not expressing myself correctly, I'm still a bit confused with Typescript.

I have a styled button from Material-UI and I'm not sure how to proceed with making this button reusable throughout the whole app. I basically would like the button to receive a prop such as `{buttonText}` or so, so I can just use it in multiple pages but with different labels.

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import ChevronLeftIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronLeft';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  backButton: {
    background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #9AA5B0 30%, #9AA5B0 90%)',
    border: 0,
    borderRadius: 25,
    boxShadow: '0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)',
    color: 'white',
    fontFamily: 'Poppins, sans-serif',
    fontSize: 15,
    height: 37,
    padding: '0 20px',
    textTransform: 'none',
  },
});

export default function BackButton(): React.ReactElement {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Button className={classes.backButton} startIcon={<ChevronLeftIcon />}>
      {buttonText}
    </Button>
  );
}
```

So when I insert the button component in another page, I could just give a value to the props and then the right label would show on my button.

```
<div>
  <PrimaryButton />
  <BackButton label={buttonText}/>
</div>
```

Any suggestions on how to make this work, using types?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your component BackButton need to accept props.

Then you make a type to props:

```
export type BackButtonProps = {
  label: string;
};
```

And add to your BackButton Component:

```
export type BackButtonProps = {
  label: string; // or buttonText
  // ...other props
};

export default function BackButton(props: BackButtonProps) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Button className={classes.backButton} startIcon={<ChevronLeftIcon />}>
      {props.label}
    </Button>
  );
}
```

Now, your BackButton has props which has a type.

Using:

```
<BackButton label="Custom Label" />
```

If the library has an internal type to his button, you can extends this type, so your type will have all properties by inheritance:

`import { AnyExistingType } from 'material-ui';`

`export type BackButtonProps = AnyExistingType & { label: string };`

Comment: Not all heroes wear capes. THANK YOU! I finally understand how the types work!